# Finding the single-tapped word in a WKWebView with Swift 4

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit

I'm using WKWebKit and would like to add the ability to copy a word from an HTML document to a separate view with a single quick tap.

The approach I'm taking is to add a TapGestureRecognizer that in turn uses JavaScript's document.caretRangeFromPoint() to locate the actual text.  But it doesn't, and I'm not sure why not.

The relevant code is below. I've left intact a little extra debugging code that prints the value of document.elementFromPoint().  That always runs as expected, returning appropriate elements on the page just to let me know that the view and location are being set correctly.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Code:

```
@objc public func HandleTapFrom (recognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer)
{    
    let myView = recognizer.view as? WKWebView
    let location: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: myView)

    // .caretRangeFromPoint which never returns anything
    var js = String("document.caretRangeFromPoint(\(location.x),\(location.y)).toString()")
    myView?.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (result, error) in
        print("-------------")
        if error != nil {
            print("\ncaretRangeFromPoint Error:", error as Any)
        } else {
            print("\ncaretRangeFromPoint Success:",result as Any)
        }
    }

    // elementFromPoint, which works as expected.
    js = String("document.elementFromPoint(\(location.x),\(location.y)).toString()")
    myView?.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("\nelementFromPoint Error:", error as Any)
        } else {
            print("\nelementFromPoint Success:",result as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging output:

```
caretRangeFromPoint Success: Optional()
elementFromPoint Success: Optional([object HTMLSpanElement])
-------------
caretRangeFromPoint Success: Optional()
elementFromPoint Success: Optional([object HTMLElement])
-------------
caretRangeFromPoint Success: Optional()
elementFromPoint Success: Optional(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Conventions_definitions#Experimental)
-------------
caretRangeFromPoint Success: Optional()
elementFromPoint Success: Optional([object HTMLParagraphElement])
```